# Webform which as a result provides unique number

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, webforms

I need to create webform where users will fill standart things like Name, Phone number, email and City. This is easiest part.
The main point of this form is to provide unique number for every person which fill the form. These unique numbers will be pre-made by me and can be provided in any form like .txt or .csv. Should not be two users with one number.
The webform should give every user one number from this list with numbers.

Is this possible only with html/css/js/jquery and if it is please help me do this.

Comment: Not possible only with html/css/js/jquery

Comment: What more do I need?